# random not working if variable == random php

Tags: php, random

This is my code:

```
$i = 0;
if($i == rand(1, 5)) {
    // Do Something
    $i = 0;
}
$i++;
```

I try to add ads between the posts if I replace rand(1, 5) with any number it's working successfully but I need to make it working by random from 1 to 5 so I try to add rand(1, 5) but it's not working.

Comment: 0 will never be between 1 and 5 ...

Comment: What is it you want?

Comment: Look at your code, look again: how can the `if` condition ever be true. Ask yourself that question.

Comment: Even though the answer is obvious for us, there is no need to downvote this. It's a legit question (even though it's an oversight from OP)

Comment: The tooltip that is given for the downvote button lets me think otherwise, @Jordumus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of `$i` to 0 before creating `rand`:

```
$i = 0;
if($i == rand(1, 5)) {
```

But in the `rand` you haven't included `0`. Which means your `rand` function will only create possibilities - `1,2,3,4,5` and not `0`

You should instead try with this:

```
$i = 1;
if($i == rand(1, 5)) {
...
```